# How to query a pair of coordinates in MongoDB with a smaller degree of accuracy than the input?

Tags: python, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am querying MongoDB to find a pair of coordinates that approximately match the coordinates I am inputting. The coordinates that I am inputting and the coordinates in my database have varying degrees of accuracy. I am using the less than/greater than the operator in pymongo in order to construct the query. However, the query quite often returns more than 1 result or no results at all. I am not sure how to deal with the difference in the accuracy of the coordinate points in the database and the accuracy of the coordinates I am querying for. Help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
def search_by_location(self, location, **round_option):
    #[42.0585616, -78.9389212]

    lat = location[0]
    long = location[1]
    initial_degree = int(round_option['int_degree'])

    #args takes location in order (LAT, LONG) unless kwargs is specified as reverse = r
    def round_lat_long(*args, **reverse_instructions):
        if reverse_instructions['reverse_option'] == 'r':
            initial_lat = args[1]
            initial_long = args[0]
        else:
            initial_lat = args[0]
            initial_long = args[1]

        int_lat = str(initial_lat)
        int_long = str(initial_long)

        degree_lat = len(int_lat.split('.')[1])
        degree_long = len(int_long.split('.')[1])

        uncertainty_lat = (10 ** (degree_lat + 1))**(-1)
        uncertainty_long = (10 ** (degree_long + 1))**(-1)

        lat_range = [lat - uncertainty_lat, lat + uncertainty_lat]
        long_range = [long - uncertainty_long, long + uncertainty_long]

        return lat_range, long_range


    rounded_details = round_lat_long(long, lat, reverse_option='r')

    results = self.geoCoords.aggregate([{"$match": {"$and": [{'location.coordinates.0': {'$gte': rounded_details[0][0], "$lt": rounded_details[0][1]}},
                                                             {'location.coordinates.1': {"$gte": rounded_details[1][0], "$lt": rounded_details[1][1]}}]}}])

    for i in results:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Without understanding your data...my approach would be to create a wide enough search range for the coordinates to insure that I always get at least the result I'm looking for, and possibly others.  Then, if I get multiple results, I'd compute the distance between the target coordinates and each entry in the returned result, and pick the one with the shortest computed distance as the match.

Comment: I've never used it, but isn't that what the Geospatial indexes and `$near` is for?